# Prevent shaky div when the button is clicked

Tags: css, html

I added a border-bottom to the button and when button is clicked border-bottom is removed and button is moved 3px down to create press effect. But when button is clicked the div below the active div also moves down and up.

This screenshot can make things clear.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div id="contactus">
        <a class="dropcontact" href="javascript:void(0)">Contact Us</a>
        <div id="contact-container" class="body">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="Name" /></li>
                <li><input type="text" placeholder="Email" /></li>
                <li><textarea placeholder="Message"></textarea></li>
                <li><input type="submit" value="send"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer-container" class="body">
            <span>&copy; All Rights Reserved 2014. Design By Mohit Chawla.</span>
            <div class="social">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images/social/facebook-3-128.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images/social/pinterest-4-128.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images/social/twitter-4-128.png" alt=""></a>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </footer>
```

**CSS** of the button

```
#contact-container input[type="submit"]{
    border: none;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #ffb851;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;font-size: 1.6rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e5e5e5;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#contact-container input[type="submit"]:active{
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't change the border width, change the border colour:

```
#contact-container input[type="submit"]:active{
    position: relative;
    top: 3px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
```

This way the sizes remain constant, and don't affect the layout/sizing.